# Resource Data In SoftLayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm developing resource graph such as Bandwidth, usage, memory, and cpu in detailed device using SL java client. Data retrieved from api are different from the graph on control portal.

These are data from graph on control.softlayer.com

```
Date                        CPU Value
2016-03-03T10:00:00-06:00   0.67
2016-03-03T10:30:00-06:00   0.86
2016-03-03T11:00:00-06:00   0.84
2016-03-03T11:30:00-06:00    1
2016-03-03T12:00:00-06:00   0.82
```

These are data from SL API. getCount() is CPU value.
getType() : cpu0

```
getCounter() : 0.26266666666667
getDateTime() : 03 03 2016 10:00:00-0600
dt.hashCode() : 1396398841
****************************************
getType() : cpu0
getCounter() : 0.42433333333333
getDateTime() : 03 03 2016 10:30:00-0600
dt.hashCode() : 1574026271
****************************************
getType() : cpu0
getCounter() : 0.591
getDateTime() : 03 03 2016 11:00:00-0600
dt.hashCode() : 1955972951
****************************************
getType() : cpu0
getCounter() : 0.57966666666667
getDateTime() : 03 03 2016 11:30:00-0600
dt.hashCode() : 357719181
****************************************
getType() : cpu0
getCounter() : 0.55033333333333
getDateTime() : 03 03 2016 12:00:00-0600
dt.hashCode() : 1379547114
****************************************
```

I've used this api to get CPU data. 
List dataList = Guest.service(client, deviceID).getCpuMetricDataByDate(startDate, endDate, null);

Memory data API
List dataList = Guest.service(client, deviceID).getMemoryMetricDataByDate(startDate, endDate);

Bandwidth data API
List dataList = Guest.service(client, deviceID).getBandwidthDataByDate(startDate, endDate, "public");

These data are not matched to the data on graph either.
pls give me your comments how i can get precise data.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommed you to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummaryData method, see below an example using the Softlayer Python client to get the bandwidth. In order to get the CPU replace the types variable with this value.

```
[
{
"keyName": "CPU0",
"summaryType": "max"
}
]
```

The example:

```
import SoftLayer
import pprint


def main():
    hardware_id = 120065

    start_date = "2015-10-03"
    end_date = "2015-10-12"

    # []SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type
    types = [
        {
            "keyName": "PUBLICIN",
            "name": "publicIn",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        },
        {
            "keyName": "PUBLICOUT",
            "name": "publicOut",
            "summaryType": "sum"
        }
    ]

    client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env()
    hw_object = client.call('SoftLayer_Hardware_Server',
                            'getObject',
                            mask="mask[metricTrackingObjectId]",
                            id=hardware_id)
    result = client.call('SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object',
                         'getSummaryData',
                         start_date,
                         end_date,
                         types,
                         3600,
                         id=hw_object['metricTrackingObjectId'])
    pprint.pprint(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the result of CPU usage was an average data for 30 minutes. But I can't still find Java API to get usage of bandwidth.

Comment: For bandwidth the code I sent you should work, just change the period 3600 to 1800. If you are still having issues in java let me know.