# What are the conversion rules in the SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBillingCyclePublicBandwidthUsage’s return value?

Tags: python, api, bandwidth, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I’m developing total usage for bandwidth. And I tried a lot of method to get total usage for bandwidth. The result always different from portal site while they are nearly. I don’t know whether the rules is wrong or not. Because the return value of API SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getBillingCyclePublicBandwidthUsage(amountIn and amountOut) are decimal. So I did as following:

```
result = bandwidth_mgt.sl_virtual_guest.getBillingCyclePublicBandwidthUsage(id=instance_id)
amountOut = Decimal(result['amountOut'])*1024   #GB to MB
amountIn = Decimal(result['amountIn'])*1024  #GB to MB
print 'amountOut=%s MB amountIn=%s MB' %(amountOut, amountIn)
```

The result is ‘amountOut=31.75424 MB amountIn=30.6176 MB’.
But the portal site’s result is 33.27 MB and 32.1 MB. There is 1.5MB different. why? regard~

[picture of portal site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf9z1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the expected behavior the values are not exactly the same, this is because the portal uses another method to get that value, if you want to get the same value you need to use the same method.

check out these related forums.

- [Bandwidth summary per server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308040/bandwidth-summary-per-server)

you need to use the method: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummaryData

The values returned by the method are the used to create the chart in control portal.

I made this code in Python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
vsId = 24340313

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
vgService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']
mtoService = client['SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object']


try:
    idTrack = vgService.getMetricTrackingObjectId(id = vsId)
    object_template = [{
      'keyName': 'PUBLICIN',
      'summaryType': 'sum'
    }]

    counters = mtoService.getSummaryData('2016-09-04T00:00:00-05:00','2016-09-26T23:59:59-05:00',object_template,600, id = idTrack)

    totalIn = 0
    for counter in counters:
        totalIn = totalIn + counter["counter"]

    object_template = [{
      'keyName': 'PUBLICOUT',
      'summaryType': 'sum'
    }]

    counters = mtoService.getSummaryData('2016-09-04T00:00:00-05:00','2016-09-26T23:59:59-05:00',object_template,600, id = idTrack)

    totalOut = 0
    for counter in counters:
        totalOut = totalOut + counter["counter"]

    print( "The total INBOUND in GB: ")
    print(totalIn / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 )

    print( "The total OUTBOUND in MB: ")
    print(totalOut / 1000 / 1000 )

    print( "The total GB")
    print((totalOut + totalIn) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000 )

except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:    
    print("Unable get the bandwidth. "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

regards

Comment: What is unit of the 'counter' property? Bytes? Or bits? If I set the 'summaryPeriod' is 86400 seconds, then I got an array of SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object_Data that include 'counter'. If I want get the total bandwidth used in September, do I sum all of 'counter' properties? What is calculate rules? regards~

Comment: The units are bytes, and to get MB you must use this:  result / 1000 / 1000. Notice that I am using 1000 instead 1024. Also you need to change your summaryPeriod from 86400 to 600 otherwise you will get a different result.

Comment: you need to get the data for PUBLICIN and PUBLICOUT (set the value in the keyName property). Then sum the result of them and you will get the total

Comment: Ah and yes you need to sum all the counters