# What is the unit for SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest:getBandwidthDataByDate

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Do you know what is the `unit` for `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest:getBandwidthDataByDate`?
Bit, byte or Octect?

I found some mismatching between the return value from `API` and `portal`.
Thanks.

Comment: what are the miss matching please add examples of you get using the API and what you get in the portal

Comment: My teammate ChrisM add some examples about miss matching. Can you help to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that you are using will return an "average: bandwith usage, but the portal uses another method which returns a "sum" value. So the values will not be the same, but they will nearly.

Another thing to point out is that the API does not return bytes/per second, it returns the bytes used by the interface in a peiod of time. what I can see in your result of the api is that period of time is 5 minutes.

so let's convert the data with that information:

646793.0 bytes in 5 minutes

converting to bytes per second (5 minutes = 300 seconds)
646793.0/300  =  2155.976 bytes/second

converting to bits
2155.976 * 8 = 17247.808

converting to kilo bits (note we are not using 1024 )
17247.808 / 1000 = 17.247 KB/s

As I told you the value is closer, but not the same due to the method used if you are looking the exact value you have to use the getSummaryData method. here an example in java [Getting bandWidth data in SL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061200/getting-bandwidth-data-in-sl)

Regards

Comment: Thank you very much! It's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, it is in bytes per second.

Answer (score 0):

Here I added an example for April's question.

[Portal Bandwidth Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3Oal.png)

I got the datas by SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest:getBandwidthDataByDate.

[getBandwidthDataByDate's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPvfV.png)

It showed that 'counter': 646793.0, if the "unit" is bytes per sec, 646793.0Bps*8/1024 != 16.62Kbps