# What are the options for SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Following on from this question:

[Resource Data In SoftLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987800/resource-data-in-softlayer)

I'd like to use the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getSummaryData call to get Memory information, not CPU or bandwidth.

The answer is great but I can't find a list of valid options to pass to the Container_Metric_Data_Type. The documentation only lists the fields, not what strings are valid and what they do for the query:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type

Can you link me to a reference about which fields are valid and what the various different summary types are and how their behaviour differs.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to know what strings are valid use this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object/getMetricDataTypes

it will return what are you looking for. Just in case to get memory information you need to use this:

```
{
        "keyName": "MEMORY",
        "name": "memory",
        "summaryType": "average"
    }
```

Regards