# Result too large for Softlayer API response

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

API: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest//getCpuMetricDataByDate.json?startDateTime=2020-03-16T14:57:06&endDateTime=2020-04-16T14:57:06&resultLimit=0,1

The response: 
{
    "error": "API request failed. Expected result size too large, please update the query.",
    "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_ApiRequestFailed"
}

Are there any flags I can set in the query to avoid that ?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I got the same error even trying with different vs, using long and short time intervals. This method does not support result limit. Please open a ticket, they will help you with this issue. If you want, you can use this other api call "SoftLayer_Metric_Tracking_Object::getSummaryData " to get the same result, see the following forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987800/resource-data-in-softlayer

Comment: thanks. I opened a support ticket for the same.